# How to add shortcut-key to create a New Text File in Dolphin

Tags: shortcut-keys, dolphin

I am using KDE+Dolphin and when I need to add a new folder I either go the long way with "Right click > Create New > Folder...", or use the F10 shortcut key.

Another option I use a lot is "Right click > Create New > Text File..." but it has no shortcut key. I entered the "Configure Keyboard Shortcuts..." menu to add a shortcut key for creating a Text File, but to my surprise there is no such option.

I reviewed the shorcut's configuration file and noticed that "create_dir=F10" is the option to create a new folder:
What would be the shortcut configuration option for creating a text file (is it possible)?
How about adding shortcut keys for other file types, such as HTML?

Answer (score 2):

`System Settings` > `Shortcuts` > `+Add Application...` > Select your favorite Text Editing Application > Finally Give it a hotkey/shortcut.

Once Kate, Kwrite, Nano, or whatever you selected is open, you can now use `Ctrl + S`  or the appropriate Save As hotkey, select location, name and save the file.

#### EDIT

A better method:

- You will need Xdotool installed and Kdialog (which is already installed with KDE)
- Create a new empty file (.sh script file) name it "createtext.sh" paste this in it -->
- for this script to work you need to enable full path in title bar, from dolphin preferences. [image: Show full path dialog box]

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

path=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname | awk -F ' —' '{print $1}')
file="new file"
extension=txt
filename="$file.$extension"
a=0
while [[ -f $path/$filename ]]; do
    a=$((a + 1))
    filename="$file ($a).$extension"
done

userfile=$(kdialog --inputbox "Create new file in $path" --title "New Text File" --geometry 420x50 "$filename")

if [[ -f $path/$userfile ]]; then
    kdialog --error "Please choose a unique file name" --title "File exists"
    exit 1
else
    touch "$path/$userfile"
    exit 0
fi
```

- save, right click on it --> properties -- > permissions --> tick on "Is executable"
- Now open Settings > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts
- Create a new group, name it Dolphin_Custom
- fill comments as show in the picture [image]
- Pass to the conditions tab
- click on "New" ---> Active Window...
- fill comments as show in the picture [image]
- Now click on new again
- set it up like this - make sure Window Types is set as "Normal" [image]
- Click on new again -- create another one like this.
- Window Type as "Desktop" [image]
- Now inside that group create a new global -- command url shortcut [image]

Now link it to the script file we made before. Give it a trigger.
We're done

[image]

Comment: Amazing answer! Could you post some link to some resource information on how this works, what all those Dolphin/Desktop settings do?

Comment: they limit the script to create new file.txt only in Dolphin or Desktop. so that it doesn't get triggered when using other apps.

Answer (score 1):

I came up against the same problem. Creating new text documents is a HUGE part of my workload, and this would save a lot of time.

Unfortunately, I have not yet found a way to make a shortcut key for it. (Though I'm investigating Xbindkeys -- with that, you can (globally) assign console commands to keyboard shortcuts *but* I need to figure out how to make it aware of what window has focus and what folder dolphin has open, so that the console command knows what folder to create the new text document in. And then I'd need to write a script that shoots up a pop-up window asking for the document name... As you can see, definitely not quite there yet.)

Anyway, I do kind of have a bit of a workaround that may help you.
If you go to: dolphin's menu --> Configure Toolbars... you can add new items to the toolbar, and one of the items you can add is 'create new'.

Once that's added to the toolbar, that streamlines things a *little bit*.

Before: right click empty area --> click create new --> click text document

After: click create new --> click text document

Not much, I know, but it is a little bit faster.

Maybe send a feature request to the dolphin developers for this keyboard shortcut? Adding new (not assigned by default) keyboard shortcuts is usually fairly easy, and developers are often happy to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As new shortcuts cannot be easily added to Dolphin (they can, as seen in the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1441877/925128)!), here're some workarounds:

- With shortcuts and Dolphin embedded terminal: press F4 to open terminal where you want your file, then write `kate` or other text editor to open a (yet unnamed) text file there; with Kate, it is also possible to write `kate -n myfile`, to open it with a name.
- With a new, top-level context menu: create (1) a file like `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/create_new_text.desktop` and (2) a script

Inside the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0

for f in "$1/"new*.txt; do
  if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
    ((c++)) 
  fi
done

f="$1/new-$c.txt"
touch "$f"
kate "$f"
```

Inside the `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
Icon=kate
Actions=new-file
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin,inode/directory
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel

[Desktop Action new-file]
Name=New text file
Icon=kate
Exec=/path/to/the/script %f
```

Thanks to @schrodigerscatcuriosity - who answered under [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/673850/341192).

Answer (score 0):

Another strange method i found is with a software called Autokey-gtk --- > its very good!

You can easily make a script like this one, to do exactly what you want. If you use Window Filter options you can select where the script may be executed.

In KDE. For example here i made a script to create a new text file in Dolphin or Desktop only.

```
winClass = window.get_active_class()
if "dolphin.dolphin" in winClass:
    keyboard.send_key("<menu>")
    keyboard.send_key("c")
    keyboard.send_key("t")
    
elif "plasmashell.plasmashell" in winClass:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    keyboard.send_key("<menu>")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    keyboard.send_key("n")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    keyboard.send_key("t")
```

[image]